# Need clarification about logic behind precedence of operators

Tags: c++, operator-precedence

Currently skim through about c++, but at below example my brain stuck.
at the `res` variable, example have preincrement of `a`,`b` and `c` integer values.

When I print it out first one have output of `a = 1, b = 0, c=0`

at the second part output is `a = 1, b = 0, c=0`

```
    int a, b, c;
    a = 0;
    b = 0;
    c = 0;
    res = ++a || ++b && ++c;
    cout << '\n'
        << " res = " << res
        << ", a = " << a
        << ", b = " << b
        << ", c = " << c << endl;
    a = b = c = 0;
    res = ++a && ++b || ++c;
    cout << " res = " << res
        << ", a = " << a
        << ", b = " << b
        << ", c = " << c << endl;
```

both of them I'm expecting output as `a = 1, b = 1, c=1` because I have already incremented variables.
From output I understand if after `||` operator, nothing is evaluated? I need clarification. Thanks.

Comment: Lookup [short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation). Evaluation of subexpressions stops as soon as the end result is unambiguously determined.

Comment: @dxiv very good page and comment. Thanks